# What is known about the representation theory of the symmetric group over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

There is a lot of material available about the representation theory of the symmetric group over $\mathbb{C}$ and fields of characteristic $0$. In particular, there is the decomposition of the group algebra
$$
\mathbb{C}S_n = \bigoplus_{\lambda \vdash n} S^{\lambda}
$$
where the $S^{\lambda}$ are the Specht modules, which are irreducible and pairwise disjoint over $\mathbb{C}$.

All the resources I could find ignored the characteristic $p > 0$ case, or said that it was hard in general when $p\vert n!$, but what of the (simple?) case when $p = 2$?

What is known about the decomposition of $\mathbb{F}_2S_n$ or $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_2S_n$ into irreducible modules, particularly the number of irreducible components?

Comment: Sorry, I calculated the transpose of what you wanted. It is fixed now.

Comment: There is an accepted answer already, but I should remark that over prime characteristic $p\leq n$ the group algebra is no longer semisimple, and that makes a (vague) answer to your question being "most of the Specht modules aren't even simples or semisimple, so we can't talk bout irreducible decompositions"... By the way, it is also not too difficult to determine whether a Specht is simple if you know about the block theory of symmetric group using partitions and abacus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The textbook by [James–Kerber (1981)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=644144) has lots of the (then) recent developments and is a standard reference. [Kleshchev (2005)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2165457) has more recent developments.

Here are the composition lengths of the Specht modules for the first 8 symmetric groups:

$$\scriptsize\begin{array}{r|rr}
n& \\\hline
1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
4 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
5 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1\\
6 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
7 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
8 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 4 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
\end{array}
$$

Here are the max composition lengths (the trivial rep always has CS length 1)

$$\scriptsize
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19\\\hline
MaxCL&1&1&1&2&3&4&3&8&8&12&12&33&33&59&47&128&131&216&217\\
\end{array}
$$

The composition lengths still have a wide range, though not as bad as previously indicated.

You can ask [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) for any particular symmetric group up to $n \leq 19$ using `List(DecompositionMatrix(CharacterTable("Symmetric",n) mod 2),Sum)`

The partitions corresponding to each entry are given in `List(CharacterParameters(CharacterTable("Symmetric",n)),x->x[2])`

### Old wrong answer:

The following are the lists of composition lengths of the projective covers of the irreducible $\mathbb{F}_2[S_n]$ modules.

$$\scriptsize\begin{array}{r|rr}
n & \\ \hline
1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 \\
3 & 2 & 1\\
4 & 4 & 3\\
5 & 6 & 3 & 2\\
6 & 12 & 6 & 6 & 1\\
7 & 8 & 3 & 6 & 6 & 4\\
8 & 20 & 9 & 18 & 14 & 6 & 2\\
9 & 32 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 18 & 6 & 8 & 4\\
10 & 56 & 24 & 22 & 44 & 18 & 3 & 6 & 12 & 12 & 1\\
11 & 60 & 32 & 17 & 24 & 26 & 12 & 18 & 24 & 22 & 12 & 5 & 8\\
12 & 156 & 108 & 47 & 60 & 84 & 18 & 48 & 8 & 30 & 36 & 26 & 10 & 6 & 4 & 2\\
\end{array}$$
$$
%\tiny
%\begin{array}{r|rr}
%13 & 264 & 84 & 49 & 92 & 35 & 24 & 76 & 32 & 42 & 70 & 24 & 12 & 16 & 30 & 24 & 12 & 10 & 10\\
%14  & 480 & 248 & 240 & 130 & 80 & 204 & 20 & 28 & 142 & 48 & 40 & 80 & 80 & 24 & 36 & 24 & 3 & 14 & 24 & 5 & 20 & 6\\
%15  & 376 & 240 & 112 & 96 & 96 & 134 & 96 & 80 & 48 & 78 & 96 & 48 & 56 & 20 & 20 & 248 & 124 & 108 & 65 & 32 & 18 & 16 & 24 & 30 & 15 & 30 & 1\\
%16  & 916 & 876 & 672 & 207 & 432 & 72 & 268 & 384 & 120 & 374 & 168 & 136 & 108 & 268 & 28 & 144 & 14 & 63 & 40 & 54 & 84 & 30 & 84 & 28 & 8 & 60 & 54 & 30 & 4 & 6 & 10 & 6\\
%17  & 1560 & 320 & 780 & 261 & 240 & 304 & 432 & 269 & 372 & 208 & 384 & 134 & 120 & 324 & 80 & 112 & 164 & 60 & 132 & 190 & 48 & 116 & 66 & 40 & 108 & 96 & 96 & 56 & 30 & 51 & 48 & 20 & 30 & 60 & 20 & 42 & 15 & 2\\
%18  & 2696 & 884 & 2120 & 640 & 224 & 1256 & 416 & 736 & 124 & 392 & 1100 & 160 & 376 & 28 & 326 & 108 & 340 & 68 & 80 & 618 & 236 & 316 & 184 & 24 & 168 & 71 & 280 & 30 & 60 & 196 & 174 & 30 & 100 & 20 & 192 & 84 & 14 & 68 & 12 & 34 & 40 & 15 & 68 & 15 & 5 & 20\\
%19  & 3976 & 1340 & 932 & 1168 & 908 & 720 & 960 & 800 & 536 & 264 & 680 & 368 & 504 & 140 & 590 & 460 & 100 & 288 & 132 & 354 & 562 & 444 & 432 & 120 & 80 & 547 & 252 & 154 & 128 & 108 & 136 & 160 & 128 & 360 & 228 & 100 & 252 & 60 & 70 & 134 & 6 & 80 & 81 & 148 & 66 & 64 & 52 & 30 & 40 & 84 & 3 & 25 & 40 & 15\\
%\end{array}
$$

There seems to be a pretty wide range.